# Update Local JSON Files after React App Build

Tags: json, reactjs, electron

I have a rather complicated question, therefore I want to give a small preface of what I want to accomplish, but feel free to Skip to the question part, if this is to long for you. :)

PREFACE:
I currently study computer science as my second bachelor and work part time for a company that is in the automotive industry and we are engineering electric components for an OEM. We use Citrix for our daily business. I got assigned by our project manager to implement a software which visualizes and tracks our KPI, like open tickets etc.. Simultaneously it should work a bit like a project management tool, add comments etc.

Due to the fact that we work for the OEM and use Citrix I can't build any Software that needs to be "installed" in the IT eco system of the OEM. Therefore I decided to "mis-use" web-technologies, such as React.

QUESTION PART:
I currently develop a React App together with some other libraries like Chart.js.
My plan is to run the npm build script and then take the whole build directory and put it up on our companies network drives from which one can open the index.html and therefore use the tool.
Concurrency should not be an issue since only a handful of people, mainly our CEO will use this tool. I have done this before with static "websites" and there obviously everything works just fine.

The issue now is, that I get updated JSON files in which the project KPIs are saved every month.
My goal initially was to just update the JSON files of my built React Website and consume that data. But this doesn't work.

So is there any way, that I setup up the whole thing, so that I have some separate directory like data in my build directory and that the React App reads and writes to these JSONs after the React App is already built? Can it help to built an Electron App around that and should this then still work at our OEM customer?

I hope this was not too confusing. Thanks for everybody who took their time! have a nice day :)

Comment: Have you considered using express as a backend to serve the files?

Comment: due to the restrictions of the OEM we work for, any "server-side" solutions including express.js is not feasible. I simply can't start any sever on a localhost for instance in their IT environment. 
So my App should be "client-side" only and able to be updated by updating JSON files which hold the data of the various graphs etc. 
But thanks for your suggestion!